# PDO query using dynamic parameter (arrays)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am working out a function that is meant to query to the database using PDO. I am working with arrays to execute. I am getting error HY093. Below is my code

```
//my function 
function test_function($statement,$data,$connect)
{
    $gg = implode(',',$data);
    $sth = $connect->prepare($statement);
    $sth ->execute(array($gg));
    $r_result = $sth->fetch();
    $show_result = $r_result['0'];
    return $show_result;
}

$datas = array("':ids' => 1"," ':stats' => 1");
$showsh = test_function("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE col1 > :ids AND col2 = 
    :stats",$datas,$con);
echo $showsh;
```

Any guidance will be helpful.

Comment: Your `$dates` array contains 2 strings, not key => value pairs, because you've quoted both. You then turn it into a straight string, and pass it inside another array. This means none of your parameters are being bound.

Comment: First you `$gg = implode(',',$data);` and then `$sth ->execute(array($gg));`, at which point `$gg` will be an array with one comma-separated string (with the keys lost). Why `implode`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first error is in the creation of the array. You're creating an array with 2 strings, instead of an array with 2 key/value pairs. It should be this:

```
$datas = array(':ids' => 1,':stats' => 1);
```

Next up is inside of the function. You're turning the `$data` variable into a string, then passing that inside of an array into your query. Forget all that, and just pass `$data` into your execute.

```
$sth = $connect->prepare($statement);
$sth ->execute($data);
```

Comment: When edited as guided. I am getting the error: Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]:

Comment: Can you edit your post with your current code, as well as the full error message? If I remember right, HY093 is mismatched parameters, which means `$data` should have 2 key/value pairs matching `:ids` and `:stats`

Comment: This has worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Refactor `$datas` to `[":ids" => 1, ":stats" => 1]`
Then edit the function:

```php
function test_function($statement,$data,$connect)
{
    $sth = $connect->prepare($statement);
    $sth ->execute($data);
    $r_result = $sth->fetch();
    $show_result = $r_result['0'];
    return $show_result;
}
```

If you must not change the `$datas` format, you must refactor it within the code. Something like:

```php
$correctData = [];
foreach ($datas as $item) {
    $elements = explode("=>", $item);
    $key = preg_replace("/\s\'/", "", $elements[0]);
    $element = preg_replace("/\s\'/", "", $elements[1]);
    $correctData[] = [$key => $element];
}
$showsh = test_function("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE col1 > :ids AND col2 = 
    :stats",$correctData,$con);
```

**Edited:** `preg_replace("(/\s)(\')/", "",...` to `preg_replace("/\s\'/", "",...`

Comment: I have done as guided I am getting the following errors
1. Notice: Array to string conversion
2. Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in

Comment: I've just edited the comment. Anyway, can you please specify which line triggered the notice? And it is not clear why the PDO Exception was triggered as I see no parameter "number" in the code provided

Comment: Line 4: Notice: Array to string conversion in
Line 4: Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]:

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Aynber for your answer. I am posting an answer using the ? instead of the :. In this answer I am not using the associative array.

```
function test_function($statement,$data,$connect)
{
    $sth = $connect->prepare($statement);
    $sth ->execute($data);
    $r_result = $sth->fetch();
    $show_result = $r_result['0'];
    return $show_result;
}
$datas = array(1,1);
$showsh = test_function("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE col1 >? AND col2 = ?",$datas,$con);
echo $showsh;
```